# Parse saves unique Object wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Ive been trying to register username "NataMio" into channels but its being registered under channels like ["global","NataMio"]. but it supposed to be ["NataMio"], anybody faced this issue ? on Android version of my application its registering it as ["NataMio"].

```
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"NataMio" forKey:@"channels"];
//    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        // code

    }];
```

Comment: In your test, seems it contain global in default. So you can just set "channels" to ["NataMio"] directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test, seems it contain "global" in default. So you can just set "channels" to ["NataMio"] directly.

Replace the following code:

```
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"NataMio" forKey:@"channels"];
```

With:

```
 currentInstallation.channels = @[@"NataMio"];
```